# Detect and parse a time range in a format like "2-4pm" for Amazon Lex scheduling bot

Tags: javascript, regex, string, amazon-lex

Short version: Given user input like `I'm going to be out of the office from 2-4pm` or `I'm out of the office from 10am-noon tomorrow`, how can I isolate the time range so I can split it on the dash and process it as a Start and End time?

Long version in case another solution would work:

I'm working on an Amazon Lex bot for out of office scheduling. My utterances are set up in phrases similar to `I'll be out of the office from {StartTime} to {EndTime}` which are working great if users type the times in a format like `2pm to 4pm`. However, some users are saying `I'll be out of the office from 2-4pm` or even worse `10am-noon`. Because Lex utterances are required to be formatted like sentences that can be spoken aloud to Alexa etc, it won't let you use dashes, so I can't create an utterance like `{StartTime}-{EndTime}` to tell it to expect dates in that format.

I already have a Lambda validation function set up so I can do custom processing on the user's input, but I'm not sure how to isolate that piece of the string so I can parse it into my `StartTime` and `EndTime` slots.

Comment: Short answer: Create a lambda to do your preprocessing. If you look at the top of your Intent inside of Lex, you'll find a 'Lambda initialization and validation' field. If you set this, it will pass in your sessionAttributes to the specified Lambda function. There, you can do your manipulation and return the slot types the way your bot needs them :)

Comment: I already have a Lambda set up to do my preprocessing - the question is how to do this specific preprocessing because I'm not sure how to isolate the data I want from the string around it.

Comment: You can try to use a Regex expression to match the times. There is no 'easy way' to do this. You'll have to build in the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for the regex:

```
\b(\w+)\s*-\s*(\w+)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXyg6X/1)

Comment: Thank you! Modified it a little bit to allow for `:` like `12:00pm` and to make it a single capture group: `/(\b(?:[\w\:]+)\s*-\s*(?:[\w\:]+)\b)/i`